# Block Diagram - $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, but $y(t)$ does not exist, only $y'(t)$

Tags: laplace-transform, causal-diagrams

I have the transfer function: $$H\left(s\right)=\frac{s+50}{s\left(s+1\right)\left(s+3\right)}=\frac{Y\left(s\right)}{X\left(s\right)}$$
and:
$$H_1\left(s\right)=\frac{1}{s\left(s+1\right)\left(s+3\right)}$$
If I am trying to get to the ODE, I receive:
$$x(t)=y'''\left(t\right)+4y''\left(t\right)+3y'\left(t\right)$$
Since I dont have an output $y(t)$, how do I paint the block diagram?
is it okay if my output is y'(t)? if I define $h(t)=y'(t)$ and thus I have $h(t)$ as output? or it is no good?

Comment: I don't see any issue having $y$ as an output. The ODE implies the existence of a signal $y$ since what is $y'$ without $y.$

Comment: You can still draw the system diagram, but at the final step, when you took $y'(t)$ as output, insert an integrator and obtain what you want.

Comment: the problem is, we are not allowed to use integrator, only: Sum, $\frac 1 s$ and multiplication

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Problem is, I do not have y in my ODE, so how can I put it in block diagram? I need to have y there, no?